# Issue with .gitignore/.slugignore syntax in order to exclude files

Tags: heroku

I am trying to use a `.slugignore` file to ignore certain files i.e. all jars in the lib directory.

There are a certain number of files within the directory I want to exclude but my pattern only finds 8 files:

```
Deleting 8 files matching .slugignore patterns.
```

Contents of `.slugignore` (problematic pattern):

```
bignibou-server/build/install/bignibou-server/lib/*.jar
```

Content of `lib` directory:

```
total 243992
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     79420 23 mai 17:41 HikariCP-2.2.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     69409 23 mai 17:41 activation-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    445288 23 mai 17:41 antlr-2.7.7.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    167735 23 mai 17:41 antlr-runtime-3.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      4467 23 mai 17:41 aopalliance-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     47359 23 mai 17:41 asm-4.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     38090 23 mai 17:41 asm-commons-4.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    117529 23 mai 17:41 aspectjrt-1.8.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   1863302 23 mai 17:41 aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    667677 23 mai 17:41 bignibou-client.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff  62487001 23 mai 17:41 bignibou-server.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      3161 23 mai 17:41 bridge-method-annotation-1.13.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     60282 23 mai 17:41 classmate-1.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    575389 23 mai 17:41 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    185140 23 mai 17:41 commons-io-2.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    284220 23 mai 17:41 commons-lang-2.6.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    412739 23 mai 17:41 commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     61829 23 mai 17:41 commons-logging-1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    111119 23 mai 17:41 commons-pool-1.6.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    108036 23 mai 17:41 commons-pool2-2.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff         0 23 mai 18:16 contents.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    313898 23 mai 17:41 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   1006424 23 mai 17:41 ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff  13732594 23 mai 17:41 elasticsearch-1.3.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   2904456 23 mai 17:41 embedded-redis-0.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    282753 23 mai 17:41 flyway-core-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   2256213 23 mai 17:41 guava-18.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      3896 23 mai 17:41 guava-annotations-r03.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    101818 23 mai 17:41 guava-base-r03.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     47499 23 mai 17:41 guava-io-r03.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   1695977 23 mai 17:41 h2-1.4.187.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     75324 23 mai 17:41 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   5272790 23 mai 17:41 hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    135566 23 mai 17:41 hibernate-ehcache-4.3.8.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    647572 23 mai 17:41 hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    113371 23 mai 17:41 hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    634265 23 mai 17:41 hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     38596 23 mai 17:41 jackson-annotations-2.4.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    225348 23 mai 17:41 jackson-core-2.4.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   1076162 23 mai 17:41 jackson-databind-2.4.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     16467 23 mai 17:41 jackson-datatype-hibernate4-2.4.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     76551 23 mai 17:41 jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    714194 23 mai 17:41 javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     30724 23 mai 17:41 javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     57183 23 mai 17:41 jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     11558 23 mai 17:41 jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     27717 23 mai 17:41 jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     16615 23 mai 17:41 jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.11.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    314394 23 mai 17:41 jedis-2.5.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    588001 23 mai 17:41 joda-time-2.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     33015 23 mai 17:41 jsr305-1.3.9.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      4736 23 mai 17:41 jul-to-slf4j-1.7.11.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    489884 23 mai 17:41 log4j-1.2.17.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   1687862 23 mai 17:41 lucene-analyzers-common-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    417561 23 mai 17:41 lucene-codecs-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   2505572 23 mai 17:41 lucene-core-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    107447 23 mai 17:41 lucene-grouping-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    138341 23 mai 17:41 lucene-highlighter-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     64016 23 mai 17:41 lucene-join-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     36073 23 mai 17:41 lucene-memory-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     96659 23 mai 17:41 lucene-misc-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    212369 23 mai 17:41 lucene-queries-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    390599 23 mai 17:41 lucene-queryparser-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    104782 23 mai 17:41 lucene-sandbox-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    108358 23 mai 17:41 lucene-spatial-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    178802 23 mai 17:41 lucene-suggest-4.9.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    521157 23 mai 17:41 mail-1.4.7.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     12050 23 mai 17:41 mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    960372 23 mai 17:41 mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    228241 23 mai 17:41 ognl-3.0.8.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    455951 23 mai 17:41 querydsl-core-3.6.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    111279 23 mai 17:41 querydsl-jpa-3.6.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     32126 23 mai 17:41 slf4j-api-1.7.11.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      8861 23 mai 17:41 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.11.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    275115 23 mai 17:41 snakeyaml-1.14.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    102177 23 mai 17:41 spatial4j-0.4.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    359014 23 mai 17:41 spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     56824 23 mai 17:41 spring-aspects-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    708371 23 mai 17:41 spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    425355 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    269186 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-actuator-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    500447 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2215 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2244 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2232 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2342 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2382 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2241 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2202 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-log4j-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2255 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-redis-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2301 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2307 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2213 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff      2275 23 mai 17:41 spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     38823 23 mai 17:41 spring-cloud-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     10415 23 mai 17:41 spring-cloud-heroku-connector-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     14258 23 mai 17:41 spring-cloud-localconfig-connector-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     62014 23 mai 17:41 spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   1026330 23 mai 17:41 spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    178151 23 mai 17:41 spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   1007922 23 mai 17:41 spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    502052 23 mai 17:41 spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    186913 23 mai 17:41 spring-data-elasticsearch-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    223179 23 mai 17:41 spring-data-jpa-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    652614 23 mai 17:41 spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    259014 23 mai 17:41 spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    426669 23 mai 17:41 spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    376217 23 mai 17:41 spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    471976 23 mai 17:41 spring-security-config-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    354721 23 mai 17:41 spring-security-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    321857 23 mai 17:41 spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     66056 23 mai 17:41 spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff       261 23 mai 17:41 spring-session-data-redis-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    252550 23 mai 17:41 spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    718705 23 mai 17:41 spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    780778 23 mai 17:41 spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    799284 23 mai 17:41 thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     26676 23 mai 17:41 thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.2.7.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    224290 23 mai 17:41 thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff   2838183 23 mai 17:41 tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    237287 23 mai 17:41 tomcat-embed-el-8.0.20.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     40997 23 mai 17:41 tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.20.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    243539 23 mai 17:41 tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    134171 23 mai 17:41 tomcat-jdbc-8.0.20.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     40997 23 mai 17:41 tomcat-juli-8.0.20.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    139881 23 mai 17:41 unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff     63777 23 mai 17:41 validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff    109318 23 mai 17:41 xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

Using the above pattern, only 8 jars are deleted! I am not sure why.

Can anyone familiar with the gitignore/slugignore syntax help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `*.jar` files are pulled in as dependencies then the patterns in the `.slugignore` file will not remove them.  When you push your code to Heroku with `git push heroku master` the following happens:

1. Checkout the most recent git commit (HEAD)
2. Discard files in .slugignore
3. Build project, including download of dependencies (.jar files your project depends on)

The *.jar pattern would therefore only remove files pushed to Heroku via your git repository.

If you have unnecessary `*.jar` files then check your project configuration file, eg. `pom.xml` if using maven and exclude dependencies not needed for production in your production build.